Need Gas for Swapping or transfering ERC20 Tokens
I have 187,708,800,000,000,000 CR20 ERC20 tokens in my metamask. I need gas to be able to transfer them or swap them.

How many ETH do I need to do that
Can I transfer them or swap them for BTC or any other coin?
Thanks


You can check https://etherscan.io/gastracker for some typical prices of actions. A token transfer costs around 60000 gas for normal tokens - unsure if your token has some special functionality, in which case it might cost more. According to the website, bridging takes about 114000 gas and costs around $5 currently, so you need maybe a bit more than half of that.
Swapping will cost more, the website suggests it takes about 350000 gas, or about $17. However, you may want to try UniswapX, which should offer gasless swaps - the swap price is paid in the original tokens. In this case you wouldn't need Eth at all. But I'm not sure if it's possible for all tokens, since the token would have to support signatures ("permit" functionality).
So transfer Ether accordingly.
To swap your tokens for BTC, you either need to do some cumbersome swapping and bridging, or then utilize a centralized exchange.
Remember that gas prices fluctuate a lot. They may go down or up.

Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to do a trial swap in the Metamask extention and it looks like the cost amount is more than the Tokens value. But when I copied the C20 ERC 20 address into Etherscan website it said they were worth $760... I am a bit confused now...

The value you'd get for swapping them may be totally different than the value you see somewhere, due to liquidity issues. Just go to some real exchange (Uniswap or UniswapX for example) to see how much you'd get in reality.

Thank you for your answer and time...muchly appreciated.
